# Hive ua parser UDF gives IOException

Tags: java, hadoop, hive, hive-udf, ua-parser

I've useragent strings stored in `String` format.

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.143 Safari/537.36
```

I want  to extract browser from user agent strings. So i have used [ua-parser-java](https://github.com/tobie/ua-parser/tree/master/java) library.

Hive UDF code is as below:

```
public class BrowserInfo extends UDF{

    public Text evaluate(Text input) {

        if(input == null) return null;
        String uaString = input.toString();

        Parser uaParser= null;
        try 
        {
            uaParser = new Parser();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
         Client c = uaParser.parse(uaString);

        return new Text(c.userAgent.family);
      }
}
```

It gives me following exception.

```
Failed with exception java.io.IOException:org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Unable to execute method public org.apache.hadoop.io.Text dhruv.udf.BrowserInfo.evaluate(org.apache.hadoop.io.Text)  
on object dhruv.udf.BrowserInfo@5379d8 of class dhruv.udf.BrowserInfo 
with arguments {"Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; bingbot/2.0; +http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm)":org.apache.hadoop.io.Text} of size 1
```

Tried with `String` instead of `Text` but getting same exception.
Without hive this code works perfectly. 
UPDATE:
No detail about this in logs of hadoop or hive.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the error, you need to ensure couple of things-

1. regexes.yaml is present in packaged .jar file and its path is correct in parser.java
2. All dependent jars are also packaged in the final .jar file.

Hope this helps.